# How to prevent word split in MS Word because of line breaks?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, microsoft-word-2007

I had a Word document. I edited it on my phone, and after opening it on the computer I noticed all the words at the end of a line are split because of line breaks; for example:

```
I go to school.
```

became

```
I go to sch
ool.
```

Pretty annoying. I tried turning off hyphenation etc., but it didn't help. I would be glad if you can give me a hand! I have Office 2007 and 2010.

My goal is to fix the document already edited, prevent the words from splitting.

Comment: Give you a hand with what? What exactly are you asking for help with? To keep it from happening when you edit it on your phone or to fix the document already edited? More details are needed.

Comment: @CharlieRB to fix the document already edited, prevent the words from splitting.